# Something keeps asking my laptop to shut down

Tags: shutdown, systemd

I use Ubuntu 20.04 with i3wm. My laptop keeps shutting down randomly. To check if it was a problem with i3 or some program I was starting with i3, I switched to the default gnome environment. But there too, I kept randomly receiving the dialogue box which asks me to confirm if I want to shut down.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I really have no idea; but I'd likely start with `xev` to see if your keyboard is playing up (ie. it thinks a power key is being struck for some reason).  If that provides some clues; I'd likely boot a *live* environment (ie. none of your configs are present; a different stack and maybe an identical stack to what you're using) and see if I get the same responses there..  Where i'd start anyway.

Comment: CPU temperature OK? Use the `sensors` command from the `lm-sensors` package.

Comment: does it also happen when idling, e.g. when you leave the computer everything is fine, but when you come back with a coffee, the dialogbox is open?

Comment: @wotanii yes it also happens while idling